# How to fix the size of WebBrowser component in CodeName One?

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to use WebBrowser component, but its length is not fitting in to its parent container. 
I tried setting its length using setHeight, which failed. Could you please suggest me how can I fix this component within a fixed size container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use WebBrowser component inside of BorderLayout(in center of it).
There is no other way when is about sizing and positioning of WebBrowser.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I've tried using a way given by you with simple example. 
i.e. `Container cont = new Container(new BorderLayout());
 WebBrowser wb= new WebBrowser(); 
 wb.setPage("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>", null);
 cont.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER,wb);`

But it's not working for me. Do you have any correction or suggestion for it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry . My internet is down, it is hard to answer to questions.

Please take a look at the KitchenSink demo:

http://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Demos/KitchenSink/src/com/codename1/demos/kitchen/Web.java

You will find also other useful demos there.